# Conditionally assign value to an object of class `sf` and `data.frame`

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a map of Mexico and a `data.frame` with 300 weather stations. I drew 10km buffers around each station using `st_buffer`. The buffers are stored in `buffers` and the map is stored in `mex`.

I plotted the map and the buffers. My goal is to assign the station number of a given buffer to all the polygons that are touched by that buffer.

[image: My map and buffers look like this.]

[The map can be downloaded from this site](https://www.inegi.org.mx/app/biblioteca/ficha.html?upc=702825217341). The CRS has to be changed from 5332 to 4326 first.

These are the first two buffers:

```
> dput(buffers[1:2, ])
structure(list(station_number = 1004:1005, station_alt = c(1925, 
1844), month = c(9L, 9L), Mean_min = c(11.6, 12.75), Mean_max = c(26.9333333333333, 
26.85), months_observed = c(5L, 5L), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(list(structure(c(-102.193501864824, -102.188739639421, 
    -102.184005627476, -102.179312845387, -102.174674195097, 
    -102.170102428304, -102.165610111091, -102.161209589104, 
    -102.156912953352, -102.15273200674, -102.14867823144, -102.144762757164, 
    -102.14099633046, -102.137389285095, -102.133951513622, -102.130692440198, 
    -102.127620994743, -102.124745588492, -102.122074091026, 
    -102.119613808832, -102.117371465453, -102.115353183273, 
    -102.113564467008, -102.112010188909, -102.110694575746, 
    -102.109621197594, -102.108792958435, -102.108212088624, 
    -102.107880139208, -102.107797978126, -102.107965788291, 
    -102.108383067551, -102.109048630528, -102.109960612321, 
    -102.111116474066, -102.112513010319, -102.114146358253, 
    -102.116012008624, -102.11810481849, -102.12041902562, -102.122948264575, 
    -102.125685584399, -102.128623467869, -102.13175385226, -102.135068151548, 
    -102.138557280014, -102.142211677156, -102.146021333863, 
    -102.149975819769, -102.154064311712, -102.158275623224, 
    -102.162598234981, -102.167020326114, -102.171529806314, 
    -102.176114348636, -102.180761422931, -102.18545832979, -102.190192234944, 
    -102.194950204009, -102.199719237488, -102.204486305951, 
    -102.209238385282, -102.21396249192, -102.218645717996, -102.223275266261, 
    -102.227838484744, -102.232322901016, -102.236716255998, 
    -102.241006537204, -102.245182011349, -102.24923125622, -102.253143191741, 
    -102.256907110134, -102.260512705114, -102.263950100018, 
    -102.267209874814, -102.270283091899, -102.273161320625, 
    -102.275836660488, -102.278301762903, -102.280549851515, 
    -102.282574740994, -102.284370854233, -102.285933237938, 
    -102.287257576532, -102.288340204344, -102.28917811605, -102.289768975321, 
    -102.290111121663, -102.290203575419, -102.290046040907, 
    -102.289638907696, -102.288983250005, -102.288080824209, 
    -102.286934064475, -102.285546076523, -102.283920629526, 
    -102.28206214616, -102.279975690846, -102.277666956193, -102.275142247682, 
    -102.272408466631, -102.269473091493, -102.266344157511, 
    -102.263030234815, -102.259540405001, -102.255884236252, 
    -102.25207175709, -102.248113428804, -102.244020116654, -102.239803059918, 
    -102.235473840866, -102.231044352758, -102.226526766947, 
    -102.221933499182, -102.217277175214, -102.21257059579, -102.207826701155, 
    -102.203058535141, -102.198279208964, -102.193501864824, 
    22.0859192364704, 22.085534238459, 22.0849172382595, 22.0840699348155, 
    22.0829946611303, 22.0816943777556, 22.0801726645306, 22.0784337105961, 
    22.0764823027115, 22.0743238119113, 22.0719641785371, 22.069409895692, 
    22.0666679911626, 22.0637460078641, 22.060651982863, 22.05739442504, 
    22.0539822914556, 22.0504249624898, 22.0467322158238, 22.0429141993409, 
    22.0389814030237, 22.034944629927, 22.0308149663093, 22.0266037510087, 
    22.0223225441472, 22.0179830952551, 22.0135973109014, 22.0091772219229, 
    22.0047349503427, 22.00028267607, 21.9958326034732, 21.9913969279179, 
    21.9869878023627, 21.9826173041033, 21.9782974017556, 21.974039922567, 
    21.9698565201456, 21.9657586426917, 21.9617575018195, 21.9578640420503, 
    21.9540889110588, 21.950442430752, 21.9469345692567, 21.9435749138888, 
    21.9403726451761, 21.9373365120024, 21.9344748079369, 21.9317953488116, 
    21.9293054516035, 21.9270119146773, 21.9249209994388, 21.9230384134463, 
    21.9213692950234, 21.9199181994126, 21.918689086505, 21.9176853101771, 
    21.9169096092626, 21.9163641001814, 21.9160502712448, 21.9159689786515, 
    21.9161204441842, 21.9165042546133, 21.9171193628082, 21.9179640905543, 
    21.9190361330684, 21.9203325652003, 21.9218498493057, 21.9235838447705, 
    21.9255298191611, 21.9276824609738, 21.9300358939496, 21.9325836929185, 
    21.9353189011326, 21.9382340490429, 21.9413211744729, 21.9445718441351, 
    21.947977176437, 21.951527865515, 21.9552142064358, 21.9590261214987, 
    21.9629531875695, 21.9669846643751, 21.9711095236842, 21.9753164792958, 
    21.9795940177575, 21.983930429731, 21.9883138419203, 21.9927322494785, 
    21.9971735488044, 22.001625570641, 22.0060761133856, 22.0105129765217, 
    22.0149239940793, 22.0192970680334, 22.0236202015486, 22.0278815319759, 
    22.0320693635126, 22.0361721994319, 22.0401787737937, 22.0440780825465, 
    22.0478594139329, 22.051512378113, 22.0550269359216, 22.0583934266765, 
    22.0616025949599, 22.0646456162951, 22.0675141216445, 22.0702002206599, 
    22.0726965236163, 22.0749961619661, 22.0770928074551, 22.0789806897431, 
    22.080654612479, 22.0821099677832, 22.0833427490944, 22.0843495623444, 
    22.0851276354261, 22.0856748259297, 22.0859896271218, 22.0860711721515, 
    22.0859192364704), .Dim = c(121L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-102.366703187571, 
    -102.361953401998, -102.357231241862, -102.352549690896, 
    -102.347921620104, -102.343359752058, -102.338876625611, 
    -102.334484561146, -102.330195626451, -102.326021603316, 
    -102.321973954954, -102.318063794337, -102.31430185353, -102.310698454116, 
    -102.307263478792, -102.304006344217, -102.300935975184, 
    -102.29806078019, -102.295388628469, -102.29292682855, -102.290682108398, 
    -102.288660597189, -102.286867808771, -102.285308626848, 
    -102.283987291923, -102.282907390044, -102.282071843364, 
    -102.281482902546, -102.281142141029, -102.281050451163, 
    -102.28120804222, -102.28161444028, -102.282268489991, -102.283168358188, 
    -102.284311539362, -102.285694862952, -102.287314502445, 
    -102.28916598624, -102.291244210262, -102.293543452269, -102.296057387819, 
    -102.298779107849, -102.301701137812, -102.304815458326, 
    -102.308113527261, -102.311586303219, -102.315224270331, 
    -102.319017464311, -102.322955499685, -102.327027598133, 
    -102.33122261786, -102.335529083924, -102.339935219426, -102.344428977502, 
    -102.348998074013, -102.353630020852, -102.358312159789, 
    -102.363031696755, -102.367775736476, -102.372531317382, 
    -102.37728544667, -102.38202513547, -102.386737433981, -102.391409466519, 
    -102.396028466363, -102.400581810326, -102.405057052946, 
    -102.409441960217, -102.413724542767, -102.417893088403, 
    -102.421936193923, -102.425842796126, -102.429602201935, 
    -102.43320411754, -102.4366386765, -102.439896466719, -102.442968556219, 
    -102.445846517653, -102.448522451477, -102.450989007725, 
    -102.453239406319, -102.45526745587, -102.457067570893, -102.458634787414, 
    -102.4599647769, -102.461053858482, -102.461899009434, -102.462497873866, 
    -102.462848769613, -102.462950693293, -102.462803323512, 
    -102.462407022203, -102.461762834097, -102.460872484312, 
    -102.459738374072, -102.458363574556, -102.456751818886, 
    -102.454907492285, -102.452835620412, -102.450541855915, 
    -102.448032463222, -102.445314301624, -102.442394806679, 
    -102.439281969997, -102.435984317449, -102.432510885871, 
    -102.428871198315, -102.425075237915, -102.421133420455, 
    -102.417056565692, -102.412855867531, -102.40854286313, -102.404129401022, 
    -102.399627608343, -102.395049857261, -102.390408730704, 
    -102.385716987477, -102.380987526877, -102.376233352903, 
    -102.371467538159, -102.366703187571, 21.8658255348988, 21.8654500907327, 
    21.8648428753359, 21.8640055607182, 21.8629404523928, 21.8616504829416, 
    21.8601392038325, 21.8584107755117, 21.8564699558012, 21.8543220866349, 
    21.8519730791717, 21.8494293973302, 21.8466980397919, 21.843786520526, 
    21.8407028478924, 21.8374555023831, 21.8340534130662, 21.8305059328018, 
    21.8268228122996, 21.8230141730931, 21.8190904795087, 21.8150625097083, 
    21.8109413258889, 21.8067382437227, 21.8024648011255, 21.7981327264397, 
    21.7937539061222, 21.7893403520278, 21.7849041683784, 21.7804575185102, 
    21.7760125914911, 21.7715815686993, 21.7671765904566, 21.7628097228052, 
    21.7584929245207, 21.7542380144494, 21.7500566392588, 21.7459602416876, 
    21.7419600293812, 21.7380669443942, 21.7342916334436, 21.7306444189888, 
    21.7271352712172, 21.7237737810075, 21.7205691339423, 21.7175300854374, 
    21.7146649370543, 21.7119815140545, 21.7094871442571, 21.7071886382512, 
    21.7050922710163, 21.7032037649975, 21.7015282746776, 21.7000703726872, 
    21.698834037488, 21.697822642659, 21.697038947816, 21.6964850911841, 
    21.6961625838445, 21.6960723056696, 21.6962145029558, 21.6965887877606, 
    21.6971941389471, 21.69802890493, 21.6990908081196, 21.7003769510501, 
    21.7018838241781, 21.70360731533, 21.7055427207767, 21.7076847579041, 
    21.7100275794504, 21.7125647892714, 21.7152894595944, 21.7181941497166, 
    21.7212709260998, 21.7245113838088, 21.7279066692395, 21.7314475040767, 
    21.7351242104195, 21.7389267370089, 21.7428446864898, 21.7468673436336, 
    21.7509837044501, 21.7551825061087, 21.7594522575916, 21.7637812709972, 
    21.7681576934083, 21.7725695392421, 21.7770047229928, 21.7814510922792, 
    21.7858964611076, 21.790328643259, 21.7947354857098, 21.799104901993, 
    21.8034249054097, 21.8076836419976, 21.811869423165, 21.8159707579007, 
    21.8199763844667, 21.8238753014886, 21.8276567983526, 21.8313104848251, 
    21.8348263198099, 21.8381946391619, 21.8414061824772, 21.844452118783, 
    21.8473240710538, 21.8500141394829, 21.8525149234429, 21.8548195420695, 
    21.8569216534119, 21.8588154720916, 21.8604957854188, 21.861957967921, 
    21.8631979942385, 21.8642124503512, 21.8649985431035, 21.8655541079981, 
    21.8658776152377, 21.8659681739947, 21.8658255348988), .Dim = c(121L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -102.462950693293, 
ymin = 21.6960723056696, xmax = -102.107797978126, ymax = 22.0860711721515
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(station_number = NA_integer_, 
station_alt = NA_integer_, month = NA_integer_, Mean_min = NA_integer_, 
Mean_max = NA_integer_, months_observed = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = 1:2, class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want to write a for loop that assigns the station_number to all the the polygons touched by buffer number *i*, then *i + 1*, etc... *i.e. Assign station number 100 to all the polygons touched by staion 100's buffer.*

To do this, I tried:

```
mex$station_number <- 0
for (i in 1:300) {
  mex[buffers[i, ], ]$station_number <- buffers[i, ]$station_number
}
```

However, running the loop (or even a named case) returns:

```
Error in Ops.sfc(left, right) : operation >= not supported
```

I expected this to do the following: The polygons touched by the *ith* buffer will be assigned the *ith*'s station number.

I read that it was a problem with the `$` in [another forum](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/657). I tried escaping it using `\` and `\\` but it didn't work.

Comment: It's hard to help without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). There are example datasets that ship with `sf` that you could use here

Comment: @camille thanks. I updated the question to display my actual data. I didn't do so initially because I thought it was a matter of syntax in my loop. The example should now be reproducible. You only have to set the CRS of the map from 5332 to 4326 using `st_set_crs(mex, 5332)` and `st_transform(mex, 4326)`.

Comment: Try `st_join(mex, buffers)` when they have the same projection.

Comment: @TimSalabim that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [@TimSalabim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2555983/timsalabim), this can be done with `st_join()`:

```
install.packages("lwgeom") # required when st_join(..., largest = TRUE)
mex <- st_join(x = mex, y = buffers, left = FALSE, largest = TRUE)
```

In fact, this solution is much more accurate than the loop I was writing because of the argument `largest`. The documentations states:

> largest
>
> logical; if TRUE, return x features augmented with the fields
> of y that have the largest overlap with each of the features of x

So basically, this leaves me with the buffer that has the largest intersection over a given polygon.